# How to write a non-C-like for-loop in Swift 2.2+?

Tags: swift, for-loop, swift2

I have updated Xcode (7.3) and there are a lot of changes; C-like for expressions will be deprecated. For a simple example,

```
for var i = 0;  i <= array.count - 1;  i++
 {
      //something with array[i]
 }
```

How do I write this clear and simple C-like for-loop to be compliant with the new changes?

```
for var i = 0, j = 1;  i <= array.count - 2 && j <= array.count - 1;  i++, j++
{
     //something with array[i] and array[j]
}
```

Update. 
One more variant

```
for var i = 0; i <= <array.count - 1; i++
{
    for var j = i + 1; j <= array.count - 1; j++
    {
        //something with array[i] and array[j]
    }
}
```

And more ...

```
for var i = 0, j = 1, g = 2;  i <= array.count - 3 && j <= array.count - 2 &&   g <= array.count - 1;  i++, j++, g++
{
     //something with array[i] and array[j] and array[g]
}
```

**Update2** After several suggestions for me while loop is preferable universal substitution for all cases more complicated than the simple example of C-like for-loop (suitable for for in expression). No need every time to search for new approach.
For instance: Instead of

```
for var i = 0; i <= <array.count - 1; i++
{
    for var j = i + 1; j <= array.count - 1; j++
    {
        //something with array[i] and array[j]
    }
}
```

I can use

```
var i = 0
while i < array.count
{
    var j = i + 1
    while j < array.count
    {
        //something with array[i] and array[j]
        j += 1
    }
    i += 1
}
```

Comment: Is it important that they are done in pairs? What is it you're doing?

Comment: @Fogmeister I am comparing neighbouring elements from the same array.

Comment: Sidenote: if you use "c-like" loops, consider switching to i < array.count instead of i <= array.count - 1. Much easier to see if it's right or a bug, much less code noise.

Comment: @Eiko Thanks, its a good sidenote !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Worst case, you can convert it to a while loop.

```
var i = 0
var j = 1
while i <= array.count -2 && j <= array.count - 1 {
    // something
    i += 1
    j += 1
}
```

-- EDIT --

Because you said, "while loop is preferable universal substitution for all cases more complicated than the simple example of C-like for-loop"... I feel the need to expand on my answer. I don't want to be responsible for a bunch of bad code...

In most cases, there is a simple for-in loop that can handle the situation:

```
    for item in array {
        // do something with item
    }

    for (item1, item2) in zip(array, array[1 ..< array.count]) {
        // do something with item1 and item2
    }

    for (index, item1) in array.enumerate() {
        for item2 in array[index + 1 ..< array.count] {
            // do soemthing with item1 and item2
        }
    }
```

For your last case, you might be justified using a for look, but that is an extremely rare edge case.

Don't litter your code with for loops.

Comment: OK, thanks! Just remark. Wile expression does not look more shorter or elegant, so why they decided to deprecate the C-like loop. Is while expression more effective than for-loop?

Comment: If you want to know *why* they did it. The answer is available. https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0007-remove-c-style-for-loops.md

Comment: ++i style will also be removed :)

Comment: @Daniel T. It looks like while expression (with += or -=) is more universal substitution for  C-like for-loop than other approaches.

Answer (score 8):

charl's (old) answer will crash.  You want `0..<array.count`:

```
for index in 0..<array.count {
    // ...
}
```

If you want something like your `i`/`j` loop you can use `stride` and get `i`'s successor:

```
for i in 0.stride(through: array.count, by: 1) {
    let j = i.successor()
    // ...
}
```

Just make sure to check `i.successor()` in case you go out of bounds.

Comment: If I need to check two the elements having some elements in between  - 0 and 4, 1 and 5 .... ?

Comment: @VYT change the `for` loop to start at index 4 instead of 0 for `j`, and keep an index `i` outside of the loop initialized to 0.  At the end of the for loop, increment `i` by 1.  That should let you compare `(0,4)`, `(1,5)`, ...

Answer (score 5):

> ```
> for var i = 0;  i <= array.count - 1;  i++ {
>       //something with array[i]
>  }
> ```

Here you don't need the element index at all, so you can simply
enumerate the array elements:

```
for elem in array {
    // Do something with elem ...
}
```

---

> ```
> for var i = 0, j = 1;  i <= array.count - 2 && j <= array.count - 1;  i++, j++ {
>      //something with array[i] and array[j]
> }
> ```

To iterate over pairs of adjacent elements, use `zip()` 
and `dropFirst()`:

```
for (x, y) in zip(array, array.dropFirst()) {
    // Do something with x and y ...
    print(x, y)
}
```

Output:

```
1 2
2 3
3 4
4 5
```

For other distances, use `dropFirst(n)`:

```
for (x, y) in zip(array, array.dropFirst(3)) {
    // Do something with x and y ...
    print(x, y)
}
```

Output:

```
1 4
2 5
```

---

There are probably many solutions to do

> ```
> for var i = 0; i <= <array.count - 1; i++ {
>     for var j = i + 1; j <= array.count - 1; j++ {
>         //something with array[i] and array[j]
>     }
> }
> ```

without a C-style for-loop, here is one:

```
for (index, x) in array.enumerate() {
    for y in array.dropFirst(index + 1) {
        print(x, y)
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice and clear! What if the start is not the first element in array, i.e. for instance i is equal to 3,  i = 3 ?

Comment: @VYT: You can apply `.dropFirst(n)` to both arguments of the `zip()` expression.

Comment: Ah, I was trying to think of a way to get zip to work.

Comment: @MartinR Thanks! I don't understand anyway (after reading the https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0007-remove-c-style-for-loops.md ) why they are going to change it. I think existing C-like for expression is more intuitive and comfortable to create different variants.

Comment: @Martin R   I have updated the question and added one more variant for  C-like for-loop. How it can be transformed?

Comment: @Martin R :) and if we have three, four... var in for-loop ?

Comment: @VYT: You got many examples in the various answers now.   Try to solve it yourself. If necessary, ask a new question.

Comment: @Martin R Probably I will switch to the while expression as it looks more universal substitution for many different variant of C-like for-loop usage.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do something with subsequent pairs there are many other ways to do it.

Something like this would work...

```
var previousItem = array.first

for index in 1..<array.count {
    let currentItem = array[index]

    // do something with current and previous items

    previousItem = currentItem
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Do enumeration

```
let suits = ["♠︎", "♥︎", "♣︎", "♦︎"]
for (i, suite) in suits.enumerate() {
    // ...
}
```

or to compare neighbors

```
import Foundation

let suits = ["♠︎", "♥︎", "♣︎", "♦︎"]
for (i, suite1) in suits.enumerate() {
    let j = i.successor()
    if j < suits.count {
        let suite2 = suits[j]
        // ...
    }
}
```

or zipping and enumerating

```
let suits = ["♠︎", "♥︎", "♣︎", "♦︎"]
let combination = zip(suits, suits.dropFirst())
for (i, (s1,s2)) in combination.enumerate() {
    print("\(i): \(s1) \(s2)")
}
```

result

```
0: ♠︎ ♥︎
1: ♥︎ ♣︎
2: ♣︎ ♦︎
```

Answer (score 2):

```
for (i, j) in zip(array.dropLast(), array.dropFirst())
{
    // something
}
```

What you're *really* doing here is enumerating two parallel sequences. So, create those sequences and use `zip` to turn them into a single sequence.

Answer (score 1):

to compare neighbouring elements from the same array you can use

```
let arr = [1,2,2,5,2,2,3,3]
arr.reduce(nil) { (i, j)->Int? in
    if let i = i {
        print(i,"==",j,"is",i == j)
    }
    return j
}
```

it prints

```
1 == 2 is false
2 == 2 is true
2 == 5 is false
5 == 2 is false
2 == 2 is true
2 == 3 is false
3 == 3 is true
```

more 'generic' approach without using subscript but separate generators

```
let arr1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0]

var g1 = arr1.generate()
var g2 = (arr1.dropFirst(5) as AnySequence).generate()
var g3 = (arr1.dropFirst(6) as AnySequence).generate()

while true {
    if let a1 = g1.next(),
        let a2 = g2.next(),
        let a3 = g3.next() {
        print(a1,a2,a3)
    } else {
        break
    }
}
/* prints
 1 6 7
 2 7 8
 3 8 9
 4 9 0
 */
```